# How to achieve search with multiple input with react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a booking Hotel application and I am trying to achieve search by multiple inputs with react.js. I tried with the code below but  I  have two errors :

first error: that whenever I change the value of type room or the number of guests I get the result with the previous state, I always get the result with the previous state.the search is working fine but it using the previous state.
second error: How to achieve intersection of the two results of objects.

Or if anyone can come with a better solution.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SearchPage.css';
import RoomList from './RoomList';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const SearchPage = () => {
  const Rooms = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      description: 'Chnambre du luxe 1',
      size: 250,
      guests: '4',
      roomType: 'family room',
      pets: false,
      picture: 'pictures/pic.jfif',
      price: 1000,
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      description: 'chambre du lux2',
      picture: 'pictures/pic2.jfif',
      price: 2000,
      size: 300,
      guests: '4',
      roomType: 'single room',
      pets: true,
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      description: 'chambre du luxe 3',
      picture: 'pictures/pic2.jfif',
      price: 2500,
      size: 350,
      guests: '2',
      roomType: 'family room',
      pets: true,
    },
  ];
  const [foundRooms, setFoundRooms] = useState(Rooms);
  const [roomType, setRoomType] = useState('All');
  const [guestNumber, setGuestNumber] = useState('0');

  const HandleGuestNumber = (state) => {
    const results = Rooms.filter((room) => room.guests === state);
    return results;
  };

  const HandleRoomType = (state) => {
    let results = [];
    results = Rooms.filter((room) => {
      let rooms = room.roomType.match(state);
      return rooms;
    });
    return results;
  };

  const HandleOnChange = (event) => {
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case 'roomType':
        setRoomType(event.target.value);
        break;
      case 'guestNumber':
        setGuestNumber(event.target.value);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Sorry, we are out of.`);
    }

    let foundRooms = HandleRoomType(roomType) && HandleGuestNumber(guestNumber);

    setFoundRooms(foundRooms);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="SearchPage">
        <h1> Search</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="SearchContainers">
        <div className="SearchItem">
          <span>Room Type : </span>
          <select onChange={HandleOnChange} name="roomType">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="family room">Family Room</option>
            <option value="single room">Single Room</option>
            <option value="Luxiourious Family Room">
              Luxiourious Family Room
            </option>
            <option value="Luxiourious Single Room">
              Luxiourious Single Room
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className="SearchItem">
          <span> Guests : </span>
          <select onChange={HandleOnChange} name="guestNumber">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox link and show the expected vs actual output?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-merkle-by67t?file=/src/Components/Screens/SearchPage/SearchPage.js this is the link

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah It looks like is not waiting for the state to be updated at the level of switch and execute directly the two functions . is there any better way to do it .

Comment: Correct, the functions that set state (e.g. `setGuestNumber`) are asynchronous

Comment: Thank you @RaphaelRafatpanah you are right the functions are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `HandleOnChange` function, you are doing this:

```
let foundRooms = HandleRoomType(roomType) && HandleGuestNumber(guestNumber);

setFoundRooms(foundRooms);
```

That is almost certainly not doing what you think it is doing.

Since `HandleRoomType` always returns an array, `foundRooms` always evaluates to `HandleGuestNumber(guestNumber)`.

It sounds like you want `foundRooms` to be the rooms that are included in the arrays returned by both `HandleRoomType` and `HandleGuestNumber`.

One way you could do that is by doing another filter.

```
const roomsMatchingType = HandleRoomType(roomType)
const roomsMatchingGuestNumber = HandleGuestNumber(guestNumber)
const intersection = Rooms.filter(room => roomsMatchingType.some(r => r.id === room.id) && roomsMatchingGuestNumber.some(r => r.id === room.id))
```